# Should I archive old folders

Tags: file-management, compression, zip

I have many folders on my hard drives that contain many media files and logs for old websites I have created for clients that I rarely ever access now.

I want to know aside from compressing them what other benefits are (if any) are there from putting the files into an archive like `.zip` or `.rar` file? Are there any performance benefits?

Comment: Please explain the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic organizational purposes, compressing the folders on a per-client basis—or per-project basis—simply makes it easier to reference the material later on. I generally divide up my client work folders between the generic, sundry stuff like notes and invoices. And then have code and related assets in another folder.

I use Mac OS X and what I like to do is create an encrypted disk image using Apple’s built-in “Disk Utility” for each client so I can safely take those files, archive them somewhere and not have to worry about prying eyes checking out file contents. Just create an image that is big enough to hold your files, choose an encrypting method—I use 256-bit AES—and create the disk. Then I store these images on an external hard drive I toss in a closet that is essentially my “cold storage” for old client work; out of sight and out of mind. With hard drive prices getting cheaper, I have two of these project/client/work drives that are essentially mirrored backup copies of each other; I might not want to deal with these files but if I have to dust them off years down the line I want to make sure the data is recoverable in some way.

Another benefit of archiving is you ensure that file metadata such as access and modification dates/times are retained. This might not seem like anything significant to you, but perhaps in the future you want to create a nice portfolio of your work and want to make sure you get the timeline right? Well, by having all of the files archived you are assured that none of the files had access or modification time/date stamps mucked around with either accidentally or intentionally. Also on the legal side of things, let’s say something requires you to prove work you did was done a certain date/time? Having an archive with date/time stamps that are frozen you are in better shape when engaging in the nonsense some clients might engage in to blame you for something you might not have done.

Performance-wise, I basically think that keeping unwanted, unneeded files on your “live system” taking up space is a bad use of resources. My main system disk is about 50GB to 60GB in size. I only ever keep active client work on that. If I were to keep all client projects on my main hard drive, I would have 200GB to 300GB of dead weight just sitting there taking up space. Removing it from them main drive makes it easier for me to perform backups of the main hard drive. And it’s made it easier and quicker to recover a backup if my system drive fails.

Comment: May I ask which program you use to create encrypted disk images? an excellent answer btw.

Answer (score -2):

The main advantages of zip/rar will be:

- compressing
- encrypting
- password protected
- organize related files

I'm sure there will be other reasons... But in your case, except compressing your unused files you won't have any benefits from it.

The main benefit when caring about performance, is when you have to distribute multiple files.

- keeping related files together
- saving bandwidth and server load
- also the receiver saves download time and bandwidth

Comment: Please explain down vote?